# unable to find closest table

Tags: jquery, html

My html:

```
<div id="dvUser">
<table id="tblUser" >
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>
<input class="sfCheckBox" type="checkbox" title="view" checked="checked">
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
<input class="sfCheckBox" type="checkbox" title="edit">
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

and Jquery:

```
$('#spnBtnSave').live("click", function() {
  var checks = $( #dvUser tr:gt(0)').find('input.sfCheckbox:checked');
  $.each(checks, function(index, item) {
      if ($(this).attr("checked")) {
          alert($(this).closest('table').attr('id'));
          alert("test");
      }
});
```

alert return blank.Unable to return `table` attribute `id`.What is my mistake.Thanks.

Comment: Where is the element with id = `spnBtnSave`? `.closest()` searches _ancestor_ nodes for a match but the element `#spnBtnSave` is not a descendent of a `<table>`. Should it be `$(sfCheckBox).live(...)`?

Comment: @andyb its not a full part of HTML its so big so i consider it.`spnBtnSave` is also part of html.In my case `alert("test")` is fire means btnclick event is work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are the things I did, and here is a working [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7DxKg/):
- The `$.each` loop, can be called on a set of objects, so you don't have to make a separate array.
- I fixed capitalization in `input.sfCheckBox:checked`, previously it was `Checkbox` and the html example uses the class `CheckBox`
- I merged your selectors for the checkboxes to this `$( '#dvUser input.sfCheckBox:checked')`
- You only select checked inputs, so you don't need to test if they are checked again in the `each` loop

```
$('#spnBtnSave').live("click", function() {
  $( '#dvUser input.sfCheckBox:checked').each(function() {
    alert($(this).parents('table').attr('id'));
    alert("test");
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try this $("#dvUser").find("table").attr("id");

Answer (score 0):

```
//cache you vars
var Tbl = $("table#tblUser"),
Btn = $("#spnBtnSave"),
Row = Tbl.find("tr").filter(":first").find("input[type=checkbox]");

Btn.bind('click', function(){ // only one instance of the button so use bind instead

  $.each(Row, function(){ //dont need key indexes here
      if($(this).is(":checked")){
          alert($(this).parents("table").attr("id"));
      }
  });
});
```

Comment: Will `Row` update if he checks a box after click is bound and then he clicks the button? Also, you should use the `.parents([selector])` selector, instead of jamming bunches of `.parent()` in a row.

Comment: @andrew yeah that code was just off the top of my head(I forget fiddle exists sometimes haha).  parents() is a good suggestion

Answer (score 0):

you should avoid using `live` since it is deprecated in jQuery 1.7 instead make use of `on`.

```
$('#spnBtnSave').on("click", function() {
   $('input.sfCheckbox:checked').each(function(){
    var table_id = $(this).parents('table').attr('id');
     alert(table_id);
     });
   });
```

fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/YxYWu/